# How to pass model to Partial View in Asp .Net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How should I pass a model from View to my Controller?

I in my view I have partial:

```
<div class="parking-status">
 @Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
</div>
@section Scripts
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function () { 
    $('.parking-status').hide().load('/Home/Refresh').fadeIn('slow');
  }, 3000);   
</script>`
```

In my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Refresh(RestaurantListViewModel model)
{   
    ...some operations on model...
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_Restaurants.cshtml", model);
}
```

How should I pass the model from View to ActionResult?  I tried:

```
setInterval(function () { 
  $('.parking-status').hide().load('/Home/Refresh', { model :'@Model'}).fadeIn('slow');
}, 3000);
```

but only null was passed to Refresh() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the model back as a form submission. You would have another Refresh method in your controller that has the HttpPost decorator that the form would submit to. You need to be sure that all the data from the model is bound somewhere in the form either visibly or in hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `ajax` method to post to an action that has the **`[HttpPost]`** decorator.  The client code looks like something this:

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
       data: myJsonString }
);
```